# Javascript variable not getting more than 1

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript file attached where the variable `touch1403171021t` is declared with the value of `0`.
Problem is following: i tap one time on the div and it gets `1` as value but when i tap the second time it keeps with the value of `1` no matters how often i tap it keeps with `1`
I want that the user must tap `2` times `1` to enable and `2` to confirm, the second action is now only an alert but i will change it so far as i have solved the problem with the scripts

```
<div id="taptoread" ontouchstart="if(touch1403171021t < 2){ touch1403171021t++; }" ontouchmove="if(touch1403171021t > 0){ touch1403171021t--; }" ontouchend="if(touch1403171021t == 2){alert('ee')}; if(touch1403171021t == 1){ $('#taptoread').css({'opacity':'1'}); $('.1403171021').slideDown(170);}" style="opacity:0.7;border-radius:7px;padding-bottom:7px;background-color:lightyellow;margin:0px 7px 0px 7px;" ></div>
```

Comment: Please format your question code so it can be more easily read

Comment: Take the JavaScript and CSS out of the tag

Comment: Why would you call a variable that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure, but I think you can not run code this way in an attribute without putting it in a function first.

Try

ontouchstart="function(){if(touch1403171021t < 2){ touch1403171021t++; }}"